# Why is my while loop not stopping after I want it to?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int number = 1;
        int[] arrayNumber = new int[10];
        do {
            System.out.println("Please enter numbers (0 to stop) : ");
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayNumber.length; i++) {
                arrayNumber[i] = scanner.nextInt();
                if (arrayNumber[i] == 0) {
                    number = 0;
                }
            }

        } while (number != 0);
```

I am trying to have the user enter numbers (up to 10) and is stopped once the user enters 0. But, when 0 is entered it does not stop.

Comment: Please try to use debugger

Comment: `break;` after `number = 0;`?

Answer (score 1):

It is simply because you have an inner for loop, you're setting the number to 0 but the for loop still hasn't finished completing. Here would be the fix

This will finish executing after the user enters 10 numbers or enters 0, whichever comes first

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

int[] arrayNumber = new int[10];
int maxNums = 0;

while (maxNums < 10) {
    arrayNumber[maxNums] = scanner.nextInt();
    if (arrayNumber[maxNums] == 0) break;
    maxNums++;
}
```

This is much shorter and neater, more readable

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int number = 1;
        int[] arrayNumber = new int[10];
        do {
            System.out.println("Please enter numbers (0 to stop) : ");
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayNumber.length; i++) {
                arrayNumber[i] = scanner.nextInt();
                if (arrayNumber[i] == 0) {
                    number = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }  while (number != 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The point is that your code would work properly only if you enter 0 at the **last iteration at for loop**. You can explicitly `break` your loop to let the `while` loop process your zero value and stop the loop.

```
    do {
        System.out.println("Please enter numbers (0 to stop) : ");
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayNumber.length; i++) {
            arrayNumber[i] = scanner.nextInt();
            if (arrayNumber[i] == 0) {
                number = 0;
                break;
            }
        }

    } while (number != 0);
```